# angular material layout inconsistent cross browser behavior

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox, angular-material

I'm facing cross browser layout issues using angular material v1.0.6.

I'm aiming at having a header, a footer, and two equally wide panes in between covering all available space. The left pane must be scrollable.

This is the basic layout:

```
<div layout="row" style="height:100%;">
    <div layout="column" flex>
      <header flex="nogrow">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </header>
      <section flex layout="row">
        <div flex id="pane-one" layout="column">
          <md-content flex>
              <md-content layout-padding>
                <p>I am the scrollable content.</p>
              </md-content>
          </md-content>
        </div>
        <div flex id="pane-two" layout="column">
        </div>
      </section>
      <footer flex="nogrow">
          <h2>FOOTER</h2>
      </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now while everything works as expected in Chrome (48.0.2564), Firefox (44.0.2) does not make the left pane scrollable. It just gives it as much hight as it needs. Safari (9.0.2) behaves even differently still, but it's not that far of from Chrome.

I have prepared a little codepen to illustrate the problem:

http://codepen.io/creimers/pen/pyJGpm

Am I applying the angular material grid in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to replace the `section` with another `md-content`. I cannot really say why, but it yields the desired behavior. 
I forked your codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGLgmR

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues so I created a new project based on John Papa's HotTowel Angular.

https://github.com/aaronklaser/hottowel-materials

It's also worth noting that flex is still relatively young and not fully supported everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but honestly I don't find it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
```

```
  <header flex="nogrow" id="c1">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </header>

   <div  flex  id="scenario" layout="row" style="height:100%;">
      <md-content  flex=50 id="noscroll"><p>noscroll</p></md-content>
      <md-content flex=50>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas numquam eaque reiciendis libero perspiciatis sint obcaecati ullam officiis aliquid maiores nemo, magnam, sequi blanditiis, corrupti saepe ratione. Non, eveniet, minus.</p>

      </md-content>
    </div>



  <footer flex="nogrow" id="c3">
    <div layout="row" layout-padding>
      <h3>FOOTER</h3>
      <md-button class="md-fab"></md-button>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not very helpful as you don't provide a link that shows your suggestions are working.